# Python: String [ [k1:v1, k2:v2], [k3:v3] ] to Object

Tags: python, converters

I'm stuck with an application that outputs the following

```
[[_type:logs, _id:AVY0ofxOHiyEPsw_vkZS, _index:firewall-all-2016.07.29, _score:13.445344], [_type:logs, _id:AVY1EI1z79siNC3TEi7P, _index:firewall-all-2016.07.29, _score:13.445344]]
```

I would like to parse this text into an iterable object. But the standards approach using `ast.literal_eval` doesn't like the input.

Is there something else I can try before I start looking into str replace etc...

Thank you

Comment: the problem with `eval()` is that the strings are not enclosed in quotes. You can get what you want with 3 `replace()` functions. Is that not acceptable for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
import re

data = "[[_type:logs, _id:AVY0ofxOHiyEPsw_vkZS, _index:firewall-all-2016.07.29, _score:13.445344], [_type:logs, _id:AVY1EI1z79siNC3TEi7P, _index:firewall-all-2016.07.29, _score:13.445344]]"

parsed_1 = re.findall("\[(.*?)\]", data[1:-1])

parsed_list = []
for line in parsed_1:
    parsed_dict = {}
    for record in line.split(","):
        k, v = record.split(":")
        parsed_dict[k] = v
    parsed_list.append(parsed_dict)

print(parsed_list)
```

The output is list of dictionaries, you can itarate over it in many ways.